# How to connect to sharepoint site using credentials in vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

How should I connect to sharepoint site using credentials in vba macro?

My code:

```
Const sUrl As String = "https://MY_SITE/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle(LIB_NAME)/files"
Dim oRequest As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim sResult As String   
Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

With oRequest
     .Open "GET", sUrl, True
     .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
     .SetCredentials USERNAME, PASSWORD, HTTPREQUEST_SETCREDENTIALS_FOR_SERVER
     .send
     .waitForResponse
     sResult = .responseText
     MsgBox sResult
End With
```

I am getting "System.UnauthorizedAccessException".

Can anybody please help me on this?